# Shrink Chrome menu?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, menu-bar, big-sur

Is there any way to shrink or shorten the Chrome menu?

It has so many options that due to its length, it's preventing me to see the remainder of my icons that are shown from the right hand side (check red circle around one of the icons).

[image]

Comment: Knowing this will be useful and cool. Great photo and use case.